# ui-router animations do not work on nested views

Tags: angularjs, animation, angular-ui-router, config

Im using ui-router stages in parent-child format and cannot get state transition animations to run every time I change router state. Animations are working when I open a state for the first time, but when switching to a different sub-state no animation is shown.

My state config is following:

```
.state('nointro', {
    abstract: true,

    views: {
        "main": { templateUrl: "partials/nointro.html" },
        "content": {  }
    }
})

.state('url1', {
    cache: false,
    url: '^/url1',
    parent: 'nointro',
    views: {
        "content": { templateUrl: "partials/url1.html" }
    }
})

.state('url2', {
    cache: false,
    url: '^/url2',
    parent: 'nointro',
    views: {
        "content": { templateUrl: "partials/url2.html" }
    }
})
```

I use default ui-router suggested transition styles from FAQ.

What I want is a animation for each state change even if parent state does not change. Is this possible?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecobf71p/) with a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your styles don't use `[ui-view]` - but use `ui-view` selector =)

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kikill/ecobf71p/1/)

Comment: I feel so blind :) I'm mixing tag and attribute usage, so it does work for attribute but not for tag. Thanks, could not have found it by myself anymore.